# Is there a way to get the deploy destination in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to configure a Maven plugin in a parent POM file. I need to configure this plugin so that it runs outside of the standard Maven lifecycle through a plugin invocation.

```
mvn some-plugin:plugin-goal
```

The configuration item I'm seeking is the deploy destination for the Maven artifact. In other words, the path to the artifact in a Maven repository.

I would like to add a configuration to my parent POM like the one below.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.something.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <location>com/my/groupId/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</location>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This string (shown below in isolation) will give me the deploy destination for the target. However, it is not dynamic and can't be used in a parent POM because the groupId path (`com/my/groupId`) is hard-coded. My parent POM does not know the groupId of its children.

```
com/my/groupId/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}
```

Is there a property in Maven to get the deploy destination within a Maven repository? Or alternatively a property to retrieve the groupId as a path?

---

Also, I understand that I get create this string with a Groovy script. However, I'm not running the plugin during the standard Maven lifecycle, but instead run it as part of a plugin execution. So the Groovy script would not run.

Comment: Do you mean like ${project.plugin.configuration.deployLocation} ?

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen I'm not familiar with that property you mentioned. But, I'm looking for the deploy location for the current project, not the plugin. Essentially, a property for the single-line code snippet in my question.

Comment: What would you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The string `com/my/groupId` is hard-coded. I want to set this property in a parent POM, but I don't know the actual value for `com/my/groupId` because it will vary from project to project.

Comment: I would like to know why are you trying this and for what purpose? I have understood that you don't like to hard code things.

Comment: @khmarbaise I reworded the question. I hope the changes help explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: The maven book (http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html) talks about three implicit property types, project.*, env.*, and settings.*. I haven't tried it, which is why this isn't an answer, but something like ${settings.localRepository} may give you the root of the repo, and from there other project settings could give you the majority of the path, and the version and artifactId should give you the start of the filenames.